# How to save flink table to csv file?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink 1.4.0

I'm trying to save the results of a Table API query to a CSV file, but I'm 
getting an error. 
Here are the details:

My Input file looks like this:

```
id,species,color,weight,name 
311,canine,golden,75,dog1 
312,canine,brown,22,dog2 
313,feline,gray,8,cat1
```

I run a query on this to select canines only, and I want to save this to a 
csv file:

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = 
ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(); 
BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = 
TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env); 

String inputPath = "location-of-source-file"; 
CsvTableSource petsTableSource = CsvTableSource.builder() 
  .path(inputPath) 
  .ignoreFirstLine() 
  .fieldDelimiter(",") 
  .field("id", Types.INT()) 
  .field("species", Types.STRING()) 
  .field("color", Types.STRING()) 
  .field("weight", Types.DOUBLE()) 
  .field("name", Types.STRING()) 
  .build(); 

// Register our table source 
tableEnv.registerTableSource("pets", petsTableSource); 
Table pets = tableEnv.scan("pets"); 

Table counts = pets 
  .groupBy("species") 
  .select("species, species.count as count") 
  .filter("species === 'canine'"); 

// Convert to Dataset and display results
DataSet<Row> result = tableEnv.toDataSet(counts, Row.class); 
result.print(); 

// Write Results to File 
TableSink<Row> sink = new CsvTableSink("/home/hadoop/output/pets.csv", ","); 
counts.writeToSink(sink);
```

When I run this, I see the results from the DataSet being output:
canine,2

However I don't get any results in the output file and I see these
errors below. What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

```
2018-05-27 13:29:17,040 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1873) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row does not contain a getter for field fields
2018-05-27 13:29:17,040 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1876) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row does not contain a setter for field fields
2018-05-27 13:29:17,040 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1911) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row is not a valid POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields.
2018-05-27 13:29:17,047 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1873) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row does not contain a getter for field fields
2018-05-27 13:29:17,047 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1876) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row does not contain a setter for field fields
2018-05-27 13:29:17,047 INFO  [main] typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:1911) - class org.apache.flink.types.Row is not a valid POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing an

```
env.execute();
```

after

```
counts.writeToSink(sink);
```

In contrast to `print()`, which immediately triggers an execution, `writeToSink()` just appends a sink operator and requires to explicitly trigger the execution.

The `INFO` messages of the `TypeExtractor` are "just" telling you, that `Row` cannot be used as a POJO type, but that's fine here.